# EmbeddedKafka failed authentication due to: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are []

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I wrote a simple test using EmbeddedKafkaBroker, I created a test producer and sent a message, but my KafkaListener doesn’t get triggered, so the test fails every time. Is there a way to test my Kafka consumer so I can ensure the test code coverage? I’d like my fake Producer (producerTest) to trigger my “real” Kafka Consumer from inside the testing class and process the messages.

Kafka Consumer:

```java
@Component
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Slf4j
public class MyKafkaListener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}")
    public void consume(@Payload String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key) {
        try {
            log.info("Reading message: " +  message);
            //do stuff, process message
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while reading message from topic", e);
        }

    }

}
```

My Test class:

```java
@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = { "test-topic" })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}" })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@Disabled
@SpringBootTest
public class MyKafkaListenerTest {

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> producer;

    public static final String TEST_KEY = "x";
    public static final String TOPIC = "test-topic";

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

    @Test
    public void myKafkaListener_success_test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        //insert object first so I can later assert that it was modified after receiving message from producer

        Map<String, Object> producerProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
        log.info("props {}", producerProps);
        Producer<String, String> producerTest = new KafkaProducer(producerProps, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
        producerTest.send(new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "", TEST_KEY));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //Assertions.assertNull(condition to assert message has been processed);
        producerTest.close();

}
```

I tried debugging my code and the Kafka Listener doesnt get triggered, here's my test  application.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:9092
    jaas:
      enabled: true
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas:
          config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule  required username="{USERNAME}" password="{PASSWORD}";
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      properties:
        sasl:
          mechanism: PLAIN
        security:
          protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
        request:
          timeout:
            ms: 20000
      group-id: kafka-list-app

    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      retries: 10
      properties:
        sasl:
          mechanism: PLAIN
        security:
          protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
        request:
          timeout:
            ms: 20000
        max:
          in:
            flight:
              requests:
                per:
                  connection: 1

kafka:
  topic:
    name: ${TOPIC_NAME:profil.topic-dev}
```

I also always get the following error:

```
Connection to node -1 (kubernetes.docker.internal/127.0.0.1:51131) failed authentication due to: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are []
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to remove `@Disabled` from your Test class. The consumer listener won't be invoked if the producer didn't send anything.

I see your broker config includes JAAS / SASL properties which are missing from your producer config in the tests. Based on the error, it is failing to authenticate the client. Perhaps you should print out `producerProps` and debug that.

To use the producer properties you've defined in your config file, you'll want to use the `private KafkaTemplate<String, String> producer;` field, and not your `producerTest` local variable

Also, based on Spring Boot documentation, your `properties` entries should look like this

```yaml
properties:
    [sasl.mechanism]: PLAIN
    [security.protocol]: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    [request.timeout.ms]: 20000
    [max.in.flight.requests.per.connection]: 1
```

To add authentication to your clients from the Spring config, you need to set `sasl.jaas.config` somewhere in your Producer and Consumer configs. Otherwise, you'll continue to get auth username/password denied errors.

```yaml
properties:
    [sasl.jaas.config]: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="..." password="...";'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question, what do you mean by "you'll want to use producer field, and not your producerTest local variable instance" because my application doesn't have a producer since it's remote, it only has a consumer.

Comment: You have a `private KafkaTemplate<String, String> producer;`, which also has a send method to produce data that should be used in your tests rather than `new KafkaProducer`

Comment: Alternatively, you could disable all the SASL properties until you get a plaintext unit test working end-to-end, but you'll still probably want to use `KafkaTemplate` class

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error message if the broker doesn’t use *SASL* and you specify either `SASL_SSL` or `SASL_PLAINTEXT` for the `security.protocol` property (like you do in the `application.yaml` file in your question).

Trying instead with either `PLAIN` (in your specific case) or `SSL` for `security.protocol` will exclude that possibility.